# Callback returns NameError - Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having troubles when using callback at last method named *last*. I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'last' is not defined
```

One method above works absolutely fine even-though it uses the same logic. If anyone has any idea I would greatly appreciate the help.

**EDIT**: I've tried putting self.last but I get the same issue - this time self is not defined.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You forgot  `self` in callback definition.  `yield SplashRequest(region_2, callback=self.last, ....`

Comment: I receive a similar issue - [Link](http://prntscr.com/mncl60)

Comment: Please remember that if you want us to help you, having actual code is required; having to redo your code out of the print screen is not really an option. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to configure callback parameter to with `self.last`.
Spider methods should have strictly `self` and `response` as method arguments(not `region` and `region_2`). Otherwise `SplashRequest` will be unable to recognise `callback` function

```
   ....
        def third(self, response): #not def third(region, response)
    ........
            yield SplashRequest(region_2, callback=self.last,....


        def last(self, response): #not def third(region, response)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That worked. I will need to get better understanding of self argument.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `self`. Fix to `callback=self.last`.

Comment: I receive a similar error when I put self in front. [link] (http://prntscr.com/mncl60)

Comment: Are you doing it inside class? Maybe you have indents problem?